# autofac - the wrong keyed service is being resolved

Tags: c#, .net, autofac

I'm using [autofac](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/index.html) and trying to [pick a service implementation by context](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/faq/select-by-context.html#option-3-use-keyed-services).  The basic idea is that there are two repositories - one which connects to database Db1 and one which connects to database Db2.  I'm attempting to use keyed services to indicate which database connection is needed.

Here's the code:

```
public class Db1Repository(IDbConnection dbConnection) 
{
    // ...
}

public class Db2Repository(IDbConnection dbConnection) 
{
    // ...
}

public class ClassThatDoesSomethingSpecial(Db1Repository repository) 
{
    // ...
}

var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder.RegisterType<SqlConnection>()
       .WithParameter("connectionString",ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Db1"].ConnectionString)
       .As<IDbConnection>()
       .Keyed<IDbConnection>("Db1");

builder.RegisterType<SqlConnection>()
       .As<IDbConnection>()
       .WithParameter("connectionString", ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Db2"].ConnectionString)
       .Keyed<IDbConnection>("Db2");

builder.RegisterType<Db1Repository>()
       .WithParameter(
            new ResolvedParameter(
                (pi, ctx) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(IDbConnection),
                (pi, ctx) => ctx.ResolveKeyed<IDbConnection>("Db1")
            )
       );

builder.RegisterType<ClassThatDoesSomethingSpecial>();

var container = builder.Build();

var myclass = container.Resolve<ClassThatDoesSomethingSpecial>();
```

What should happen:
The `Db1Repository` that is injected into the constructor of `ClassThatDoesSomethingSpecial` should have an `IDbConnection` that was resolved to a `SqlConnection` to **Db1**.

Instead, the `IDbConnection` is resolved to a `SqlConnection` to **Db2**!

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens if you use `Named<IDbConnection>("Db1")` instead for each of the connection registrations?

Comment: @Amy - same issue.

Comment: I tried your code and everything works as expected : https://dotnetfiddle.net/PLE3Uz

Comment: @CyrilDurand - Thank you for the fiddle.  I do see that it works there as expected.  It's still not working in my original code, but at least now I know that it *should* work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
builder
    .RegisterType<Db1Repository>()
    .WithParameter(ResolvedParameter.ForNamed<IDbConnection>("Db1"));
```

https://autofac.org/apidoc/html/CF9E2168.htm

Comment: Wow, okay.  I'll leave the answer up so other people don't also suggest this :(